# packer.nvim: Error running config for <PACKAGE>: attempt to call a nil value

Tags: neovim, packer

When I start neovim, I'm now getting a lot of errors like this,

```
packer.nvim: Error running config for hop.nvim: attempt to call a nil value
packer.nvim: Error running config for nvim-lspconfig: attempt to call a nil value
```

What's causing these errors and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

## Update

This is answer is wrong, after changing everything back it still works. I think this may have been a packer cache issue. But that's weird because **100% I tried `:PackerUpdate` and the problem did not go away. I would probably try `:PackerCompile` but having rolled back all files I can't figure out what caused this.

---

For me, both of these errors were caused be

```
require'hop'.setup({})
```

When I changed this to

```
require('hop').setup({})
```

Everything worked. Weird [because it's documented like the top](https://github.com/phaazon/hop.nvim/blob/master/README.md#installation) and that used to work.